# prevAll() not working in more complicated DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a single sibling further up in the DOM after clicking a button. I only want to find the closest sibling upwards (in production there's a lot more HTML between the buttons, so it's more necessary to split it up this way). I'm using a `prevAll(selector:first)` to do this, and when I use a very simple version ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/NateH06/wn9go243/)), it seems to work ok. But when I do it in a way that's more similar to my actual environment, prevAll() can't seem to find the sibling element `div.googleMapsContainer`:

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div style="display: none;" class="googleMapsContainer" id="gm1">
        <div class="gmap" style="max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 400px;
            background-color: grey;" class="map">
        </div>
        This Text Should be visible after click
 </div>

 <div class="tableProcessingToolBarContainer">
      <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="appSliderContent tptSliderContent container-fluid ">
                <button class="gmapInit glassyButton">View data in Google Maps</button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div style="display: none;" class="googleMapsContainer" id="gm2">
        <div class="gmap" style="max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 400px;
            background-color: grey;" class="map">
        </div>
        This Text Should be visible after click
 </div>

    <br>

    <div class="tableProcessingToolBarContainer">
      <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="appSliderContent tptSliderContent container-fluid ">
                <button class="gmapInit glassyButton">View data in Google Maps</button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gmapInit', function() {
    console.log("here is this: ");
    console.log($(this));
    var closeThing = $(this).prevAll("div.googleMapsContainer:first");
    console.log("here is the closest: ");
    console.log(closeThing);
    closeThing.attr("style", "");
});
```

The console shows that the `closeThing` is nothing, as the prevAll was not successful. Here's a JsFiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/NateH06/twk9mtjg/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/  Get all preceding **siblings** of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.  `parent()` and `closest()` go up.  `find()`, `children()` go down.  http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Right, I'm trying to target the siblings. Is `div.googleMapsContainer` not a sibling to `button.gmapInit` ?

Comment: Siblings are on the same level.  <parent><sibling></sibling><sibling></sibling></parent> .  Any element not on that level, not inside that parent, are not siblings

Comment: .gmapInit is the only child of it's div.  It has no siblings.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, thank you. I think the commenter below has detailed how to traverse it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is working for me, I just modified your Fiddle.

I selected the parent div that was in the same scope and then used your `prevAll()` call to precise my selection. What happens when you try this in your actual Project?

Have a look:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.gmapInit', function() {
    var closeThing = $(this).parents("div.tableProcessingToolBarContainer").prevAll("div.googleMapsContainer:first");
    closeThing.attr("style", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none;" class="googleMapsContainer" id="gm1">
        <div class="gmap" style="max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 400px;
            background-color: grey;" class="map">
        </div>
        This Text Should be visible after click
 </div>
 
 <div class="tableProcessingToolBarContainer">
      <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="appSliderContent tptSliderContent container-fluid ">
                <button class="gmapInit glassyButton">View data in Google Maps</button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 <div style="display: none;" class="googleMapsContainer" id="gm2">
        <div class="gmap" style="max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 400px;
            background-color: grey;" class="map">
        </div>
        This Text Should be visible after click
 </div>

    <br>
    
    <div class="tableProcessingToolBarContainer">
      <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="appSliderContent tptSliderContent container-fluid ">
                <button class="gmapInit glassyButton">View data in Google Maps</button>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I had been confused on DOM traversal.